# ¿Como puedo obtener el número primo generado?

Tags: python, recursión, números-primos

tengo el siguiente código en el que genero un número primo aleatorio, el cual puedo imprimir por pantalla, sin embargo, a la hora de querer devolver el valor, tengo que agregar otro "return" a la función y por tanto se genera un conflicto y me devuelve la palabra "NONE" o valores erroneos que no son primos.

```
def primoaleatorio():
    num = random.randrange(30)
    for n in range(2, num):
        if num%n == 0:
            print(num, " no es primo, ", n, " es divisor.")
            primoaleatorio()
            return
    print(num, "Es primo")
```

¿Como podría obtener el valor correcto para devolverlo como parámetro en la función?
He probado a usar break, pero tampoco funciona.

Esta es la solución que yo planteo, aunque como digo, genera error.

```
def primoaleatorio():
    num = random.randrange(30)
    for n in range(2, num):
        if num%n == 0:
            primoaleatorio()
            break
    return num
```

Este es un ejemplo de ejecución normal:

```
25  no es primo,  5  es divisor.
27  no es primo,  3  es divisor.
4  no es primo,  2  es divisor.
13 Es primo
```

Gracias, un saludo.

Comment: Hola imvD! El código que has puesto tiene problemas de identación, por favor puedes editar la pregunta y corregir los errores. Te recomiendo leer [¿Cómo preguntar?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @RubialesAlberto Perfecto, ya está corregido, muchas gracias!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Al margen de la indentación incorrecta de la primera línea (el `def` debería estar más a la izquierda pero entiendo que eso ha sido un problema al copiar y pegar el código aquí), tu código no funciona correctamente por lo siguiente.

Cuando sales del bucle porque has detectado que `num` no tiene divisores, retornas el valor de `num`, pero cuando en cambio detectas que tiene un divisor no retornas nada (no hay un `return` dentro del bucle). Añadir un `return` a secas no resuelve el problema, porque `return` a secas retorna `None` y lo que quieres retornar es el primo encontrado. Lo que ocurre es que en este caso el primo no lo está encontrando esta llamada a la función, sino la llamada recursiva que contiene a `primoaleatorio()`. Es esta llamada la que se supone que te retornará un primo válido, y ese primo es el que debes retornar desde ahí. Por tanto tienes que cambiarlo a:

```
def primoaleatorio():
  num = random.randrange(30)
  for n in range(2, num):
      if num%n == 0:
          return primoaleatorio()
  return num
```

### Otras consideraciones

- Puedes reducir la cantidad de divisores a probar. En vez de llegar hasta `num-1` basta que te quedes en la raiz cuadrada de `num`. Si no has encontrado un divisor menor que la raiz cuadrada ya no lo encontrarás tampoco mayor (pues si hubiera un divisor mayor, el cociente de esa división sería menor que la raiz cuadrada, y sería por tanto otro divisor que ya habría aparecido antes).

  Con esta optimización quedaría así:

  ```
  def primoaleatorio():
    num = random.randrange(30)
    print("Probando", num)
    for n in range(2, int(math.sqrt(num))+1):
      if num%n == 0:
        return primoaleatorio()
    return num
  ```
- Entiendo que se trata de un ejercicio académico y no de un problema real. En realidad usar recursividad en este caso es tremendamente ineficiente y hasta peligroso. El mecanismo que estás usando para generar el primo consiste en probar números al azar hasta dar con uno que sea primo. Esto en sí mismo no está del todo mal (aunque corres el riesgo de probar el mismo varias veces, lo que no sería muy eficiente si ya habías comprobado antes que no era primo). El verdadero problema está en que cada vez que pruebas uno y no es primo, **la función se llama a sí misma**, sin haber retornado todavía, ocupando un marco adicional de pila.

  Esto es un desperdicio de memoria. Si pruebas 100 números antes de dar con el primero primo, tendrás 100 marcos de pila ocupando memoria innecesariamente (y luego retornarás de los 100 rápidamente uno a uno hasta llegar a la llamada inicial que retornará por fin el primo hallado).

  Además, Python impone un límite de 1000 marcos de pila anidados. Esto significa que si tienes la mala suerte de que generas 1000 números no primos, el programa romperá con un desbordamiento de pila.

## Otras soluciones no recursivas

Para arreglar estos problemas causados por la recursividad sería mucho mejor una versión iterativa (un bucle que vaya probando uno a uno los números hasta dar con uno que sea primo). Además puedes ir guardando los que ya hayas comprobado para no repetirlos.

Esta sería una implementación que hace eso:

```
def primoaleatorio():
  ya_probados = []
  while True:   # Repetir infinito (en realidad sale con return al encontrar un primo)
    num = random.randrange(30)
    if num in ya_probados:
      continue    # Probar otro
    print("Probando", num)
    for n in range(2, int(math.sqrt(num))+1):
      if num%n == 0:               # No es primo
        ya_probados.append(num)    # lo recordamos
        break                      # y rompemos el for para volver al while
    else:                          # Si agotamos el bucle for, sí era primo
      return num
```

Mejor aún sería simplemente generar la lista de primos menores de 30, o de otro número dado (puedes usar para esto una criba de eratóstenes que es muy eficiente). Entonces tu función `primoaleatorio()` simplemente usaría `random.choice()` para devolver un elemento al azar de esa lista.

Ejemplo:

```
import random
import math

def eratostenes(n):
  numeros = [True]*(n+1)           # Todos primos de momento
  numeros[0] = numeros[1] = False  # El cero y el 1 no son primos

  # Vamos a ir "tachando numeros"
  for factor in range(2, int(math.sqrt(n+1))+1):
    if not numeros[factor]:  # Si ya estaba marcado como no primo se salta
      continue
    # Todos los múltiplos de este factor (salvo él mismo) se tachan
    for indice in range(factor*2, n+1, factor):
      numeros[indice] = False  # Ese no es primo

  # Retornar la lista de números supervivientes en los que haya quedado True
  return [x for x, es_primo in enumerate(numeros) if es_primo]

def primoaleatorio(primos):
  return random.choice(primos)

primos = eratostenes(100)
for _ in range(5):              # Imprimir 5 primos al azar menores de 100
  print(primoaleatorio(primos))
```

Salida:

```
43
17
17
2
53
```

Comment: muchas gracias, tu explicación ha sido genial y he aprendido mucho. Un placer!!